# Where to change the NLS_DATE_FORMAT in oracle 11g?

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

i need to change the NLS_DATE_FORMAT  in my Stored procedure.seems like its a session variable and where should i alter the variable mask.

should it be done in global declaration or elsewhere(i mean from frontend).

Comment: `alter session set nls_date_format = '...'` https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_2013.htm#SQLRF53073

Comment: But, how to to this for a package?

Comment: Just run the SQL using `execute immediate`

Comment: Why do you want to change the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` in your stored procedure?  If your code requires strings in a particular format (or converts strings in a particular format to dates), it should be using explicit casts with an explicit format mask, in which case the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is irrelevant.  If your code is doing conversions that are based on the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, it shouldn't care what the format is, just that a particular user has asked for data in a particular format.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change a NLS parameter in a procedure then you can use [`DBMS_SESSION.SET_NLS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_sessio.htm#ARPLS68065). Given an environment that looks like this:

```
SQL> select value
  2    from nls_session_parameters
  3   where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';

VALUE
------------------------------------------

DD-MON-RR

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
---------
25-NOV-14
```

executing the procedure changes the format (note the triple single quotes):

```
SQL> begin
  2     dbms_session.set_nls('nls_date_format', '''yyyy-mm-dd''');
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
----------
2014-11-25
```

Alternatively you can use dynamic SQL, [`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/executeimmediate_statement.htm#LNPLS01317), for instance:

```
SQL> begin
  2     execute immediate 'alter session set nls_date_format = ''yyyy-mm''';
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-------
2014-11
```

**However**, as [Justin Cave notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120420/where-to-change-the-nls-date-format-in-oracle-11g#comment42744101_27120420) this is highly unusual. If you're converting between datatypes you should always do this *explicitly* with an explicit format. In the case of dates the correct function to use is [`TO_DATE()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions203.htm#SQLRF06132)